# How to set up bootstrap rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Website Im working on is a newsletter type, after each row, there should be an small banner, let's say google ads.

With an every new breakpoint, each news row will grow by 1 item

Small img to describe what Im trying to achieve

[image]

if I would use this markup

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
</div>
<div class="row banner">
 ... img ...
</div>
```

What will happens on `sm` is 4th element would collapse to the new line and md would should be find

I want 4th element in this markup to be on the new **line(row) after banner**

P.S. using hidden-* for each case isn't an option, because row would have 6th items on extra wide screens (1920px). Like this
xs - 2 items
sm - 3 items
md - 4 items
lg - 5 items
extra-lg - 6 items

And of course there are multiple lines and multiple banners and no content should be hidden

**EDIT:**

I come up with something really simple, using jquery to paste new row.

```
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    function banner_layout(num, content){
                        return $(".news-grid .col-sm-6:nth-child("+ num +")").before( "<div class='col-xs-12 content-banner text-center'>" + content + "</div>");
                    };

                    function place_banner(position, content){
                        var p = position;

                        if (p == 1){
                            if ( $(window).innerWidth() > 320 && $(window).innerWidth() < 768) {
                                banner_layout(2, content);}
                            else if ( $(window).innerWidth() > 768 && $(window).innerWidth() < 992) {
                                banner_layout(3, content);}
                            else if ( $(window).innerWidth() > 992 && $(window).innerWidth() < 1200) {
                                banner_layout(4, content);}
                            else if ( $(window).innerWidth() > 1200 && $(window).innerWidth() < 1680) {
                                banner_layout(5, content);}
                            else if ( $(window).innerWidth() > 1680) {
                                banner_layout(6, content);}
                        }
                    };

                    place_banner(1, "<img src='http://placehold.it/1000x100' class='img-responsive' />");

                    $( window ).resize(function() {
                        $('.content-banner').remove();
                        place_banner(1, "<img src='http://placehold.it/1000x100' class='img-responsive' />");
                    });

                });
```

Comment: You want to literally reorder the DOM. I think you are stuck with javascript if you want to do this. Flexbox might be able to accomplish this, but I doubt that as well, however I don't know flexbox well. You can't put the element you want after the other at a different screen res.

Comment: There is another trick, hide the div and show another div during resolution change, if you are looking for something simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1) by jQuery

Script moves columns from one row to another depending on the screen width.

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/y07re3rq/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectAfter  = $( '#after'  );
  var selectBefore = $( '#before' );

  var numBefore = 6;
  checkBefore();
  $(window).resize( checkBefore );
  
  function checkBefore() {
    var widthNew = window.innerWidth;
    if      ( widthNew <  768 ) { setBefore(2) }
    else if ( widthNew <  992 ) { setBefore(3) }
    else if ( widthNew < 1200 ) { setBefore(4) }
    else                        { setBefore(6) };
  }

  function setBefore( numNew ) {
    while ( numBefore > numNew ) {
      selectBefore.children( 'div:last-child' ).prependTo( selectAfter );
      numBefore--;
    }
    while ( numBefore < numNew ) {
      selectAfter.children( 'div:first-child' ).appendTo( selectBefore );
      numBefore++;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/* Decorations */
.col-xs-6, .col-xs-12 { color: #fff; font-size: 48px; padding-bottom: 52px; padding-top: 14px; text-align: center; }
.col-xs-6:nth-child(2n+1) { background: #69c; }
.col-xs-6:nth-child(2n+2) { background: #9c6; }
.col-xs-12                { background: #c69; padding-bottom: 16px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="before">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">Banner</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="after">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">7</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">9</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">10</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">11</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">12</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## 2) by CSS (only for fixed-height columns)

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/38w7L6jt/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* Heights */
.col-xs-12 { height: 120px;}
.col-xs-6  { height: 300px;}

/* Make free space for the banner */
                             .col-xs-6:nth-child(2) { margin-bottom: 120px; }
                             .col-xs-6:nth-child(3) { margin-bottom: 120px; }
@media (min-width:  768px) { .col-xs-6:nth-child(4) { margin-bottom: 120px; } }
@media (min-width:  992px) { .col-xs-6:nth-child(5) { margin-bottom: 120px; } }
@media (min-width: 1120px) { .col-xs-6:nth-child(6) { margin-bottom: 120px; } 
                             .col-xs-6:nth-child(7) { margin-bottom: 120px; } }

/* Move the banner down */
.row { position: relative; }
.col-xs-12 { height: 120px; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 300px; }

/* Decorations */
.col-xs-6, .col-xs-12 { color: #fff; font-size: 48px; padding-top: 14px; text-align: center; }
.col-xs-6:nth-child(2n+1) { background: #69c; }
.col-xs-6:nth-child(2n+2) { background: #9c6; }
.col-xs-12                { background: #c69; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">Banner</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">7</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">9</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">10</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">11</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I really liked your question but unfortunately right now i don't free time to solve this but a can bring a you a few insights about the resolution.

First of all, you probably need to some MVW Framework to solve this, because accordingly to the ocurrencies of yout DOM you should reorganize your HTML elements, mainly the .

I've started a plunker file that you can try to elucidate this (or maybe our stackoverflow friends). Heres is the following url [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7pYWjCqBufRkxKEk23ev?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="TestApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0-beta.10/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-6" style="background:red;">sadasdsadasdasdsadasdsadas</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-6" style="background:blue;">sadasdsa</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-6" style="background:green;">asdsadsadsa</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-6" style="background:purple;">asdasdsadas</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row banner" style="background:pink;">
    IMAGE BANNER
    </div>

  </div>


  <div ng-repeat="n in [10] | makeRange">Do something 0..9: {{n}}</div>

  </body>

</html>}
```

**Script.js**

```
   'use strict';

var myapp = angular.module('TestApp', []);

myApp.filter('makeRange', function() {
        return function(input) {
            var lowBound, highBound;
            switch (input.length) {
            case 1:
                lowBound = 0;
                highBound = parseInt(input[0]) - 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                lowBound = parseInt(input[0]);
                highBound = parseInt(input[1]);
                break;
            default:
                return input;
            }
            var result = [];
            for (var i = lowBound; i <= highBound; i++)
                result.push(i);
            return result;
        };
    });
```

The main concept is you should use ng-repeat to separate ocurrencies according to resolution.

Here's a good snippet that can help you finding the screen to filter the elements.

```
if(findBootstrapEnvironment()==="Medium"|(findBootstrapEnvironment()==="Large"|){
$scope.size="Medium"
}else{
$scope.size="Small"
}

function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
var envs = ["ExtraSmall", "Small", "Medium", "Large"];
var envValues = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg"];

var $el = $('<div>');
$el.appendTo($('body'));

for (var i = envValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var envVal = envValues[i];

    $el.addClass('hidden-'+envVal);
    if ($el.is(':hidden')) {
        $el.remove();
        return envs[i]
    }
};
```

When I come back if you didn't got your question answered yet, I will help you!